# Flashing over deck ledger with vertical panel siding (no backer ply)

Tags: deck, flashing, ledger

Replacing an existing deck with questionable ledger flashing…
The house has wood vertical panel siding and I believe it is mounted straight on the studs (no backer ply sheet).
The current ledger is mounted over the siding with the metal flashing just mounted over both the siding and the ledger board… maybe it was caulked on the back, but still seems weird. Also, with the top of the flashing visible it is not the best look.

I am wondering if I should cut the siding and slide the flashing behind it. Keep in mind it would directly in contact with studs/insulation since there is no backer behind the siding. I am uneasy that I am potentially creating a path for water to enter directly in the walls.

Edit: just came up with new option. Basically same as option 1 below (keep siding intact) but use Deck2Wall spacers instead of flashing, so water can flow freely between siding and ledger.

Any advice appreciated!

[image: ledger side view]
[image: ledger top view]
[image: options sketch]

Comment: Is it possible to get a picture?

Comment: pictures are up!

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm curious because I'm about to embark on the same thing. I'm pretty sure the t1-11 is doubling as both the siding and sheathing. I'm thinking of going with Option 2 but installing another bit of flashing above the bottom siding.